# Ho to trace dll to some nuget package

Tags: nuget-package, dotnet-cli

I'm working on relatively big solution with many projects in it. Almost each project has dependencies on some nuget packages. In the output folder `bit/debug/net6.0` of startup project I have found `BouncyCastle.Crypto.dll` and I would like to find out where it's comming from.

I have checked all the project files but there is no references to `BouncyCastle.Crypto` neither any reference in any of `.cs` files. So it must be a transient dependency.

Question is there easy way to find out nuget package from which this DLL is comming?
Is there is UI for it e.g. in Visual Studio / Resharper or if there is some command for `dotnet` CLI?

Answer (score 0):

You can use *build* with *--verbosity* flag, like this:

```bash
dotnet build --verbosity detailed
```

And then, in output you can *grep* or search for relevant dll, you'll find something like this:

```bash
1:7>Target "_CopyFilesMarkedCopyLocal" in file "/opt/.dotnet/sdk/6.0.403/Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets" from project "/SOME_PATH/SOME_PATH/SomeProjectName.csproj" (target "CopyFilesToOutputDirectory" depends on it):
   Task "Copy"
     Copying file from "/SOME_PATH/.nuget/packages/bouncycastle/1.8.9/lib/BouncyCastle.Crypto.dll" to "/SOME_PATH/SOME_PATH/bin/Debug/net6.0/BouncyCastle.Crypto.dll".
   Done executing task "Copy".
```

*from project* line, will point you to the actual project. *Copying file from* and *to* will point to the actual dll.